# New to animation in Iphone

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I am fairly new to transition and animation methods in Iphone. Can somebody pl. guide me the basics of transition and Animation in Iphone. This is needed frequently in my Apps. Can anybody tell me any link where i can Understand ABC of animation ?

Comment: Don't indent paragraphs. It treats your entire question as one very long line of code.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to Core Animation and UIView animations, you might want to look at Marcus Zarra and Matt Long's new book [Core Animation: Simplified Animation Techniques for Mac and iPhone Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321617754).  It provides a very thorough walkthrough of Core Animation, from the high level UIView animations to more complex animations involving CALayers and CAAnimations.  Bill Dudney also has an excellent [Core Animation book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356107).

As far as official documentation, the [Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) is also well-written.

There are many questions here on Core Animation, tagged with [core-animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core-animation).

Matt Gallagher has an interesting series of articles entitled "[An Asteroids-style game in Core Animation](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/02/asteroids-style-game-in-coreanimation.html)".

Finally, I teach a course on iPhone development, in which I devoted a class to Core Animation and the neat things you can do in it.  The course notes are [available for download](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/AdvancediPhoneApps.zip) ([VoodooPad](http://flyingmeat.com/voodoopad/voodoopadlite.html) format), and have quite a bit of detail in them, in addition to links to other resources and sample applications.